# Text Editor for Angular 2.0.0

Tags: angular, ckeditor, quill, rich-text-editor, ngx-quill

We have an application running on Angular 2.0.0. Is there a text editor npm library  which gives support to Angular 2.0.0.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic. Try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but beware that your second paragraph is off topic there.

Comment: Renoved the second paragraph. Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not telling you to remove it, only a notice that it might be on topic for Stack overflow, but your first question might be better on Software Recommendations.